# sanity checking for elements/events before applying methods

Tags: javascript

say, you want to apply a method from the element proto on an element that may or may not be in the dom.

typically, I used to do:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo"); // or $("foo") for mootools/prototype, whatever
if (foo)
    foo.focus();
```

though i now thought that due to flasy null and lazy &&, it can actually be written as:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo"); 
foo && foo.focus();
```

similarly:

```
var clickHandler = function(event) {
    event && event.foo && event.foo();
};


clickHandler({
    foo: function() { alert("bar"); }
});

clickHandler();
```

I have not seen this used much or at all as a pattern, which leads me to believe that it is:

- bad for readability purposes (not to me anyway)
- has cases where it will fail

Am I safe to continue using it?

http://jsfiddle.net/td6We/1/ to play with. I can't seem to break it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it *safe*?

yes <sub>in the context of the code being able to execute</sub>. The return mechanism of `||` and `&&` is consistent and well-defined. It may not be safe to use around programmers who don't understand the behavior of `||` and `&&` in JS.

Is it *readable*?

It depends on what you're doing. For cases where you're performing an action on a dom element, I highly recommend using an `if` statement. It's very easy for a single statement to turn into multiple for cross-browser usage:

```
foo && foo.bar()
```

might turn into

```
foo && foo.bar();
foo && foo.baz();
```

at which point it's much more legible as:

```
if (foo) {
  foo.bar();
  foo.baz();
}
```

However there are niche cases where it's not likely going to turn into more. I use this particular statement style all the time:

```
console&&console.log(foo, bar, baz);
```